# How do I retrieve a .jar timestamp?

Tags: java, timestamp

I'm timestamping and signing my deployed .jar files (deployed via JNLP) as part of the build process.  I'm doing error logging and would like to include the timestamp from the .jar file as a way of confirming exactly which signed build that the errors are coming from.

How do I access that timestamp from inside the running .jar?

Answer (score 1):

I m drawing upon an answer from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777870/how-do-i-use-an-ajc-build-parameter-inside-an-aspect/26780355#26780355).

It seems you can get location of jar file by following :

```
public class ClassFileHelper {
    public static URL getClassURL(Class<?> clazz) {
        return clazz.getResource('/' + clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
    }

    public static String getJARFromURL(URL url) {
        if (!url.getProtocol().equals("jar"))
            return null;
        String fileName = url.getFile();
        fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('!'));
        fileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        return fileName;
    }
}

Class clazz = MyClass.class;
URL classURL = ClassFileHelper.getClassURL(clazz);

String jarFile = ClassFileHelper.getJARFromURL(classURL));
```

Then to get the signed timestamp , I am again copying some other answer from a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647759/how-to-validate-if-a-signed-jar-contains-a-timestamp) - excuse me for my impunity!

`File f = new File( jarFile );`

`if ( f.exists() )` ->

Execute the command `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs myjar.jar` by      using `Runtime.exec(...)` - make sure the right location of `jarsigner` was passed to arguments.

parse the output which is of the form `[entry was signed on 8/2/13 3:48 PM]` to get the time stamp.

Another option is to use `keytool` in JRE :

`keytool -printcert -jarfile myApp.jar`

Comment: You're returning the OS timestamp on the file, not the signed timestamp inside the jar file.

Comment: Unfortunately, jarsigner.exe is part of the JDK and won't be available on client machines with only the JRE.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch it seems there is one more option to get jar file's certs : `keytool -printcert -jarfile myApp.jar` `keytool.exe` is available in JRE

Comment: If the timestamp is in the printcert printout, I'm just not seeing it.  Also not a big fan of shell calls to tools that may or may not be in a user's path.  There's gotta be a decent programmatic way to do this.